# Dynamic created webview how to allowpopups

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I create a webview dynamically:

```
    var webviewlo = document.createElement("webview");
    webviewlo.src = loUrl; //  + 'allowpopups' doesnt work
    webviewlo.id = 'loo';
    webviewlo.style = 'height: 100%; width: 100%';
    loElement.appendChild(webviewlo);
```

How do I add the tag 'allowpopups', like is said in the docs?

```
<webview src="https://www.github.com/" allowpopups></webview>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try:

```
var webviewlo = document.createElement("webview");
webviewlo.innerHTML  = "...your html string..."
```

You can also try using:

```
webviewlo.setAttribute("allowpopups","");
```

Comment: I need to add 'allowpopups' to webviewlo.src in proper way. I already have my src as u can see

Comment: why not declare all the parameters in HTML string and set innerHTML?

Comment: I add a new possibile solution